# Cannot find type for useTabListState in react-aria

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, react-aria

I'm testing react-aria tabs and I'm trying to add types to their [example](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/useTabList.html#example).

The thing is, I'm not sure which type to use for the props used in the tabs component. `useTabListState` uses `TabListStateOptions` but I can't find them in the packages. I checked on the repository, but it seems it's not being exported in the library.

Should I use the types from node_modules? Am I missing some strategy to find the types?

This is the current code on the page (excluding css and usage):

```js
import {useTab, useTabList, useTabPanel} from 'react-aria';
import {Item, useTabListState} from 'react-stately';

function Tabs(props) {
  let state = useTabListState(props);
  let ref = React.useRef(null);
  let { tabListProps } = useTabList(props, state, ref);
  return (
    <div className={`tabs ${props.orientation || ''}`}>
      <div {...tabListProps} ref={ref}>
        {[...state.collection].map((item) => (
          <Tab
            key={item.key}
            item={item}
            state={state}
            orientation={props.orientation}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <TabPanel key={state.selectedItem?.key} state={state} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Tab({ item, state, orientation }) {
  let { key, rendered } = item;
  let ref = React.useRef(null);
  let { tabProps } = useTab({ key }, state, ref);
  return (
    <div {...tabProps} ref={ref}>
      {rendered}
    </div>
  );
}

function TabPanel({ state, ...props }) {
  let ref = React.useRef(null);
  let { tabPanelProps } = useTabPanel(props, state, ref);
  return (
    <div {...tabPanelProps} ref={ref}>
      {state.selectedItem?.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useTabsListState` code can be found [here](https://github.com/adobe/react-spectrum/blob/main/packages/%40react-stately/tabs/src/useTabListState.ts). It takes a `TabListStateOptions<T>` which is just `TabListProps<T>` without the children. `TabListProps<T>` source code can be found [here](https://github.com/adobe/react-spectrum/blob/main/packages/%40react-types/tabs/src/index.d.ts). However, the Tabs component takes a `AriaTabListProps<T>`, which extends `TabListProps<T>`. The `<T>` is just any additional props of each tab. So I think you are looking for something like:

```
import { 
  useTab, 
  useTabList, 
  useTabPanel, 
  AriaTabListProps, 
  AriaTabProps 
} from "react-aria";
import { Item, useTabListState } from "react-stately";

function Tabs(props: AriaTabListProps<AriaTabProps>) {
  let state = useTabListState(props);
  let ref = useRef(null);
  let { tabListProps } = useTabList(props, state, ref);
  return (
    <div className={`tabs ${props.orientation || ''}`}>
      <div {...tabListProps} ref={ref}>
        {[...state.collection].map((item) => (
          <Tab
            key={item.key}
            item={item}
            state={state}
            orientation={props.orientation}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <TabPanel key={state.selectedItem?.key} state={state} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-voice-89tlws?file=/src/App.tsx) with as much typing as I can. I'm not sure all of it has the right types, but hopefully this is useful.

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you very much! How did you find the types? Sometimes I have no clue how to find the types. It's like trial and error or just replicating them locally and then having surprises when the library types are updated.

Comment: I usually start by clicking `go to definition` in VS Code, which usually takes me to the type definitions if types are available.

Comment: Usually that works, but in this case it wasn't enough for me